# Creating my own onRunningProcessChanged listener

Tags: android

Instead of using a `Handler` inside a `Service` and check the running process every 2ms, I would like to create a `listener` for that. Is it possible? I would like to do that using a `listener` because I feel listeners don't exploit battery life, and they are much more efficient than `handlers` and than using the traditional periodic check for a state of something.
I've been searching around the internet but all I could find was related to the usual OnClickListener related to the Views and etc. Is it possible to create my own Listener thne to listen to the actual running application, I would like to check if the name of the app is "com.xxx.yyy" then doSomething();

Any way to do that using the listener method?
To post some codes, my usual way is to use a Service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    hd = new Handler();
    startRepeatingTask(); //using Handler and postDelayed method recursively.
}
```